# Create a new app listing using Google Play Developer API

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Using the Google Play Developer API, there seems to be plenty of ways to make edits to an existing app.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref

Looking through the API it seems all the API requests uses "packageName".

e.g.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/edits
```

This indicates that you already need to have an app available, with at least 1 APK already uploaded.

This is fine for editing an existing app. However, how can I create a new app using the API, without an existing listing or APK added?

Comment: did you get an answer to this offline?

Comment: No I wasen't able to

Comment: Any solution for this? Is it possible to create the package automatically or does the first version always have to be manual?

Comment: There still seems no way to do this